# Is the "P" always silent in words that start with "ps"?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, silent-letter, digraphs

Is it true to say that in English always when word starts with  "P+S", the the letter p is dropped out of pronunciation and become silent?

I know about some words which behave like that, such as *psychology* and *psychiatry*. But I'm not sure if there are no exceptions, or maybe these words that I mentioned are exception.

Comment: I'm not aware of any words where an initial **ps** _doesn't_ drop the _p_ in English pronunciation. I also believe that all such words came into English from Greek roots, and were spelled with an initial Ψ.

Comment: I was going to endorse @Jeff's comment, but checking [the full subscription-only online OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/153718) it only took a few seconds to turn up ***pschent*** - (Ancient History) *A headdress of ancient Egypt, combining the white crown of Upper Egypt with the red crown of Lower Egypt, used after the formation of the State (c 3000 b.c.).* For all practical purposes, though, you could reasonably ignore "words" like that, since almost no native speakers would know them anyway (and even if they *did*, they might well "mispronounce" it by discarding the **/p/** ! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It's quite likely that even that word got into English via Greek. But I'll admit that I wasn't considering any sort of obscure words like that... :)

Comment: Before reading your last comment I'd have been quite prepared to believe that *all* English words starting with **ps** came from Greek. But since I still had the OED page open in my browser, I just checked the very next entry... ***pselaphognath*** *(Any of various minute millipedes comprising the subclass **Pselaphognatha,** having a soft integument bearing tufts and rows of bristles)*. Apparently that's from ***latin***.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the ⟨p⟩ is always silent in words that start with ⟨ps⟩. The cluster /ps-/ is not a legit onset cluster in English because it violates the Phonotactics constraints of English.

Every language has a fixed set of rules called [**Phonotactics** or **Phonotactic rules/constraints**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/268682/106592) that determine the permissible sequences of sounds. In simple words, Phonotactics studies what sounds go together, and where can they be found in a word.

For example, the sequence /pn-/ is allowed in Greek, but not in English. That's why the P in the word *pneumonia* is pronounced in Greek, but silent in English because English doesn't allow a cluster of *PLOSIVE* (/p t k/) + *NASAL* (/m n ŋ/) in the same syllable.

According to English Phonotactics constraints, English cannot have an [onset](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272711/106592) cluster beginning with a plosive /p t k/ followed by a fricative /s z ʃ ʒ/. Therefore, the ⟨p⟩ in *psychology* and *psychiatry* is silent. Similarly, the ⟨t⟩ in the word *tsunami* is also silent in English.

Also note that the plosive is only silent when it's in the onset and precedes a fricative in the same syllable. In the syllable coda, however, the sequence 'Plosive + Fricative' is allowed.

---

<sup>**/slashes/** represent phonemes (sounds) while **⟨angled brackets⟩** represent spelling.</sup>