# Why 'TEFL" is pronounced with Schwa /tef.əl/ although it's an abbreviation?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, phonetics, vowels

Why 'TEFL" is pronounced with Schwa /tef.əl/ although it's an abbreviation?

What is the logic behind this of insertion a schwa sound?

Comment: What's the logic of pronouncing SQL with a schwa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'TEFL' has two possible pronunciations:

- [ˈtef.əl]: with a schwa
- [ˈtef.l̩]: with a syllabic<sup>1</sup> L

The reason Anglophones insert a schwa is because the tautosyllabic coda cluster<sup>2</sup> */-fl/ is not found in English ([Phonotactic Constraints](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/265526/106592)) and native speakers are unfamiliar with that cluster so they insert a schwa there or make the L syllabic. If it were */tefl/ (single syllable), it would violate the phonotactics of English.

---

NOTES:

1. [Syllabic consonants](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272360/106592) are consonants that are capable of making a syllable on their own. In English, /l m n r/ can be syllabic when they come right after an obstruent (/p t k s g f/ etc) in an unstressed syllable for instance the second syllable of *button* is usually pronounced as a syllabic *n* (not every individual pronounces it with a syllabic *n* though)
2. 'Tautosyllabic' means *being the same syllable*, for example, the *n* and *t* in *ant* are in the same syllable so they're tautosyllabic. 'Coda' refers to the consonants after the nucleus (usually vowel) of the syllable (e.g. *nt* in *ant*). According to [English Phonotactic Constraints](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/265526/106592), English doesn't have OBSTRUENT + SONORANT in the same syllable in the coda. (Obstruents: *p, t, k, s, k, f* etc. Sonorants: *l, m, n* etc.) Note that this is entirely different from *OBSTRUENT + SYLLABIC consonant* sequence.